# ajax is not capturing actual response from Struts2 action class

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, action

The below ajax method firing method in action class and action class failing (with null pointer exception with all stacktrace); but my ajax always goes into success: function.? Please let me know why this is happening.  What should I change in my ajax call?  Do I need to submit; am just trying to pull information and capture success from action.
+
The below ajax call on Click not firing action class in IE. works good in firefox.

This is a method in action class.

```
public String pullData() {

    try {
        logger.debug("Pulling Data..!");
        data.getInformation();  -> //throws null pointer exeption.
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.LOG.warn("Error while trying to execute quartz job: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

jsp

```
<input id="pullDataButton" class="button" type="button" value="Pull"  />
```

ajax method

```
$("#pullDataButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax( {
      traditional: true,
      type: "POST",      
      url: "PullData.action",
      async: true,
      success: function(response) {
          $('#placeHolder').html('Data Pulled!').css({color:'green'});
      },
      error: function(e) { 
          $('#placeHolder').html('Data Pull Failed!').css({color:'red'});
      }       
    });
});
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="pullData" method="pullData" class="com.pay.code.PullDataAction">
        <result name="input">mainInfo.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">mainInfo.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">mainInfo.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you return an error code there's no way for the JavaScript code to know something bad happened-you're returning a normal request result. JS is *presicely* capturing the actual response from S2, and you can prove that by looking at the response using Firebug or other browser dev tools.

I don't recall if the current dispatcher result allows setting an HTTP response code-if it does, set it to an error. If it doesn't (I don't believe it does), you can hack the existing result type to allow setting a code–that's what I've done if you specifically need an HTTP error response (or other) code.

Another option is to return JSON and use the contents of the JSON to determine both error status and new DOM content, and do a bit more work on the client side.

Another option is to put the information in the JSP you're sending back, e.g., use an action property to determine some of the HTML content–so instead of doing that on the JS side, do it in the JSP. Or return different JSP altogether, possibly embedding/including the "constant" part that doesn't change.

The best option depends on your skill set and requirements.

Comment: Is there way that action's  return of 'SUCCESS' and 'ERROR' can be traced on response or by some means??  If this cannot be done I have to use a JSON or param/hidden fields.  I just need to know if this is SUCCESS or ERROR in executing the method.

Comment: @user1769790 Only if you set an HTTP response code: if S2 returns a normal result, JS has no way of knowing that *S2* thinks it's an error. `"error"` is just a name. You could just encode the error/non-error info in the JSP and skip all the extra work, e.g., if there's a status field set then have error CSS in the JSP.